# Cannot connect to a shared printer on local network; error 0x00004005

Tags: windows, networking, printer

I have a shared printer, connected to computer in local network, model is HP Laser Jet 2420. I am trying to connect to it from another computer. I see it in network, when I type address of computer in windows explorer. But when I try to connect to it, I get error 0x00004005.
[image: Cannot connect to printer error 0x00004005].
When I try to connect to it using a Local port (Control panel > Devices and Printers > add printer > add a local printer or network printer with manual settings > Create a new port :: Local port), I get such error:
[image: access is denied on local port]

I tried to set up GPEDIT.MSC > Administrative Templates > Printers > Point and Print Restrictions to Disabled and it did not help.
My computer and host computer are in same workgroup. Both computers use win 10. It was working before like charm, I was able to connect and print on that printer, but suddenly it stopped working.

How do I nicely share this printer?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it got fixed with recent updates of Windows. Also I have enabled all sharing on remote computer